# What is the difference between a shibboleth and a dog whistle?

Tags: meaning, shibboleth

As I understand it, although the term shibboleth is most commonly used for words where the pronunciation varies between different groups (eg the pronunciation of "herb" between the US and the UK), it also includes cases (that wikipedia describes as furtive shibboleths) where instead the word has additional meanings within a group of people (eg 420, 1488).

A dog whistle seems to have a very similar meaning - using a word or phrase which has a very simple meaning to the majority of the population, that communicates something else to a subset of the audience (eg "family values").

Does this mean that a dog whistle is a furtive shibboleth (or the usage of a furtive shibboleth)? Is it possible to have a dog whistle that doesn't use such a shibboleth? Does a dog whistle have to be a deliberate usage of such a shibboleth as a shibboleth?

Also, every example I have found of dog whistles are appealing to homophobia/transphobia/xenophobia/etc. Is it possible to have a dog whistle that doesn't appeal to intolerance or phobia?

Edit: wiktionary definitions:
[shibboleth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shibboleth)
[dog whistle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog_whistle)

Wikipedia definitions:
[shibboleth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth)
[dog whistle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_whistle_(politics))

Comment: Please add relevant linked and attributed definitions for both terms. I'd say a shibboleth is a distinctive whereas a dog-whistle is a subtly coded message. Not very synonymous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Definitions added.

Comment: I beg to differ. Attributed hotlinks added.

Comment: Usually, a ***shibboleth*** is used by people *outside* a group, to identify those who are *in* the group (sometimes the "in-group" don't even *realise* something is a shibboleth; if they did, they might avoid it so as not to give themselves away). But a ***dog whistle*** is used by people *in* the group to communicate with others in the group (it's mostly people *outside* the group who won't recognise it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers does that mean that the example of 1488 is not an example of a shibboleth, as it those outside the group (typically) don't realize the deeper meaning and how it can be used to identify?

Comment: I think "the example of 1488" is just the latest conspiracy theory nonsense, on a par with the idea that the Russians rigged the Brexit and Trump votes. But if it *was* in widespread use, I'd say it was a "watchword" (by which members of the in-group recognise each other, not by which *outsiders* penetrate a group's "policy of secrecy").

Comment: http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~kemmer/Words/shibboleth

Comment: Humans can’t hear a dog whistle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Shibboleth

This word comes from the Old Testament. Soldiers from the tribe of Ephraim were trying to cross over the Jordan river, but another tribe, the Gileadites, controlled the river. So to identify the enemy soldiers, the Gileadites had the soldiers of Ephraim say a word they'd probably mispronounce.

> They said, "All right, say 'Shibboleth.'" If he said, "Sibboleth," because he could not pronounce the word correctly, they seized him and killed him at the fords of the Jordan.

(Judges 12:6, NIV)

More recently, during WW2, Allied forces had a shibboleth, according to this [Wikipedia entry](http://Countersign%20(military)):

> A well-known sign/countersign used by the Allied forces on D-Day during World War II: the challenge/sign was "flash", the password "thunder", and the countersign (to challenge the person giving the first code word) "Welcome"

The thought was: even if a German soldier knew the sign and countersign, he would mispronounce these words as *toonder* and *velkom*. The inability to produce these sounds made it a shibboleth to detect the German soldier.

So a shibboleth is used as a quick verification whether a possible enemy is a friend or foe. It is a password.

## Dog Whistle

The [Wiktionary article](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog_whistle) cited by the OP says:

> A high-pitched whistle, inaudible to humans, used to train dogs.

> That which is understood only by a narrow demographic.

> (politics) A political allusion or comment that only a certain audience are intended to note and recognize the significance of.

In the main usage, the whistle is inaudible to humans, but may be heard by dogs. In the political usage, an utterance may be heard by anyone, but only a subset can understand it.

A *dog whistle* is a covert message that everyone hears, but only a few understand.

Again, going back to WW2, there were messages that were broadcast on the radio that were only to be understood by the French Resistance.

> Molasses tomorrow will bring forth cognac.

([Source](https://www.warhistoryonline.com/world-war-ii/the-bbcs-messages.html))

This utterance was heard (by all) on the radio, but had a special meaning to the Resistance.

## Conclusion

The *shibboleth* is used as a password to determine if someone is within a given group. It is a spoken word, given individually.

The *dog whistle* is a covert message, which is broadcast to a large, undifferentiated group, but only comprehended by a small demographic.

I will quote @FumbleFingers comment verbatim:

> Usually, a **shibboleth** is used by people *outside* a group, to identify those who are *in* the group (sometimes the "in-group" don't even *realise* something is a shibboleth; if they did, they might avoid it so as not to give themselves away). But a **dog whistle** is used by people in the group to communicate with others in the group (it's mostly people *outside* the group who won't recognise it).

Comment: Does that mean that the dog whistle has to be constructed around a shibboleth?

Comment: Not necessarily. Hillary Clinton called half of Trump supporters a "basket of deplorables." She further defined "deplorable" as "racist, sexist, homophobic, xenophobic, Islamaphobic." This was a dog whistle to her blue political base: covertly stating, "We're not like them. We deplore them.". But "deplorable" is not s shibboleth. Not even a die-hard yellow dog Democrat would use it a password, asking: "Are you a racist? Are you afraid of homosexuals?" Who would respond in the affirmative?

Comment: And to your question: "Is it possible to have a dog whistle that doesn't appeal to intolerance or phobia?" I would say that the Clinton "deplorable" dog whistle is appeal *against* intolerance, xenophobia, and Islamaphobia.

Answer (score 0):

A shibboleth is clear to everyone.  Even those who do not know what a reference means can pick up that it's something a group would know.

The point of a dog whistle is that it is alleged to be secret, heard only by the in-group, just as a dog can hear a dog whistle, and a human can't.  Which means, of course, that if you declare that "Saying 'X' means 'Y' to group Z *alone*" -- well, the person who says it claims to hear it, and therefore it is not a dog whistle.  Indeed, a common use of "dog whistle" is to make frankly paranoiac claims that a person's political opponents believe whatever is most convenient for the speaker to have them believe, regardless of evidence to the contrary.

Comment: If a shibboleth is clear to everyone, does that mean that the furtive shibboleth (as described on the wikipedia page) is not a shibboleth? The examples meet the description of dog whistle that you give, but not shibboleth.